# Close security screen alert Internet Explorer Pop-up using VBA and Windows API

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, internet-explorer, automation

I´ve been devoloping an automation with VBA that uses Internet Explorer as the main browser. But every time I run my code, a little screen appear, saying about security:
[it´s in portuguese but i don´t think the content is important](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKhYN.png).

I don´t know exactly if there´s any way deactivate the message, but this solution will be useless, becasue the code is itended to run on other computers.

One solution that I had founded was to "sending keys" like:
`SendKeys ("~")`
But with this method maybe can happend so many issues. So I had the idea to take the handdle screen code or **HWND** and use it with the windows API function *SendMessage* to close it:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
```

Perhaps I don´t know how to take the hwnd from this screen because it seems to be a just pop-up

*as my code and generic i won´t put it here*

I readed some other post but any of them helped me to solve

Comment: *"i don´t think the content is important"* - The first step in solving a problem is understanding the problem. Don't proactively reject the idea that understanding the problem is indeed valuable. What does the error message read? And how can we reproduce it? A [mcve] would help.